# Graphlytic Desktop error Neo4j Graph is not running.Please start Neo4j Graph and then restart Graphlytic

Tags: neo4j, graphlytic

I'm using Graphlytic Desktop installed in Neo4j Desktop and I'm seeing this error: "Neo4j Graph is not running. Please start Neo4j Graph and then restart Graphlytic".
I'm new to this and don't know what to do.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Identify what problem you have encountered

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue when you start the Graphlytic Desktop app from the left menu in Neo4j Desktop project and no Neo4j Graph is Activated.

Solution: start any Neo4j Graph and then start the Graphlytic App again.
Check out the official guidelines here: https://graphlytic.biz/blog/how-to-install-graphlytic-in-neo4j-desktop